# The file extension for the requested URL does not have a handler configured to process the request on the Web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have configured rewrite rules in my application on IIS. However when I try to enter the page which should redirect me to ASP.NET Core Web API action I get an error:

```
The file extension for the requested URL does not have a handler configured to process the request on the Web server
```

Note: Changing static files handler mapping doesn't help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'll answer my question:
Error doesn't seem to be very descriptive. What solved the issue is installing `Application Request Routing Cache` and **enabling proxy** in IIS Manager in `Application Request Routing Cache -> Server Proxy Settings -> Enable Proxy`

Comment: I ran into the same issue while trying to get a Python/Flask application to work, and your solution worked for me as well. Thanks!

Comment: this fixed the issue for me as well, thank you for providing this answer as I've been tearing my hair out trying to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a static handler mapping as indicated in the diagram below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I run onto the same problem with IIS hosted Angular Universal website calling .NET Core API.
I had to move the setup from one working server to another I faced the problem on the new one, which confused me a lot.
Searched a lot in the space and configured many things as

- app pool to Not managed code
- folders permissions
- authentication and authorization rules

At some point I found out I need to install [.NET Core 6 Hosting bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-6.0.25-windows-hosting-bundle-installer), which adds two IIS modules -

> AspNetCoreModule

and

> AspNetCoreModuleV2

The other thing that I had to do is to

> Application Request Routing Cache -> Server Proxy Settings -> Enable
> Proxy settings

as mentioned above accepted answer - https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-6.0.25-windows-hosting-bundle-installer